# Opsworks ruby sass performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, sass, aws-opsworks

we're trying to migrate our application to Opsworks, to use their nice AutoScale UI, and chef features, but unfortunately we faced performance issues.
After installing everything we ran a stress test we hardly received 8-10 rps at 100% CPU usage. 
On production nodes we can see 45 rps on 50% cpu usage.
Thanks to new relic we drilled down that the issue is that sass.render takes much better time that it takes in prod. I tried other version of Ruby, other version of ubuntu, other AMI, install RVM and run application with RVM - nothing helps - if the server was provisioned with OpsWorks Chef recipes performance we receive is only 10% in compared to our clean install environment.
Running profiling tools like perf tool i can see very different functions of ruby in use.

Healthy:

```
 Samples: 16M of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 21491349414, Thread: ruby(30970)
  17.35%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_exec_core                    
  14.01%  libc-2.19.so        [.] 0x0000000000080bb8              
   8.14%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] st_lookup                       
   5.86%  libc-2.19.so        [.] malloc_usable_size              
   4.23%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_search_method                
   3.06%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] gc_heap_lazy_sweep              
   2.45%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_call_cfunc                   
   2.29%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] newobj_of                       
   2.02%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_call_iseq_setup_normal       
   1.74%  libc-2.19.so        [.] malloc                          
   1.66%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_call_iseq_setup
```

Opsworks:

```
 Samples: 198K of event 'cpu-clock', Event count (approx.): 37862860026
  52.81%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] match_at
   7.69%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] mbc_enc_len
   7.23%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] is_mbc_newline_ex
   4.95%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] onigenc_mbclen_approximate
   4.00%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_exec_core
   2.19%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] is_mbc_newline
   1.99%  libc-2.19.so        [.] 0x0000000000098b4d
   1.24%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] st_lookup
   0.75%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_search_method
   0.55%  libruby.so.2.1.0    [.] vm_call_cfunc
   0.54%  libc-2.19.so        [.] malloc_usable_size
```

Any thoughts what can lead to such a bad performance there?

Comment: That is weird. Why would you even be rendering sass at runtime (as opposed to precompiling?)

Comment: we got things precompiled, but part of our SAAS user can customize his view, so we need to rerender it instantly

Comment: Is this a SAAS or Sass question?  Please make sure you're using the correct tags.

Comment: it's Sass question - performance issues with css generations